# Django REST can't write custom Throttle and getting ImportError:

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

folder structure api/api_views.py

**api_views.py**

```
class BurstRateThrottle(UserRateThrottle):
    scope = 'burst'


class SustainedRateThrottle(UserRateThrottle):
    scope = 'sustained'
```

**settings.py**

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_THROTTLE_CLASSES': [
        'api.api_views.BurstRateThrottle',
        'api.api_views.SustainedRateThrottle'
    ],
    'DEFAULT_THROTTLE_RATES': {
        'burst': '60/min',
        'sustained': '1000/day'
    }
}
```

Getting this error `: Could not import 'api.api_views.BurstRateThrottle' for API setting 'DEFAULT_THROTTLE_CLASSES'. ImportError: Module "api.api_views" does not define a "BurstRateThrottle" attribute/class.`

Comment: Does `api_views.py` import some models too? Try moving your throttle classes to their own `throttles.py` file

Comment: @Iain Shelvington api_views was not my app. It was just an folder where I wrote some api code. As it wasn't an app so I was getting error.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest checking the official documentation which is very straightforward.
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/throttling/#custom-throttles
Moreover, There are certain models that need to be overridden in order to be able to implement a fully working custom throttling solution. However, You can use the built-in functionality that throttling modules offer and customize it based on your needs.
Simple Example:

```
from rest_framework.throttling import UserRateThrottle

class ThrottleCheck(APIView):
    throttle_class = UserRateThrottle
    throttle_scope = "THIS SHOULD BE THE NAME YOU DEFINE IN YOUR SETTING FILE"
    def get(self,request:Request)-> Response:
        """
        SOME CODE GOES HERE.  
        The throttle would be triggered here
        """
The last words, Ideally if you can handle throttling from your Nginx side would make more sense Since on production this might be challenging using the Throttle class of Django-rest-framework.
Hope this helps. Happy Hacking
```